# Can't Install Vanity A/B Testing on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vanity

I'm trying to install [Vanity A/B Testing](https://github.com/assaf/vanity) in my Rails App, but I can't even get the example from the GitHub page working. I've generated the vanity models and run the migrations and made the experiment files, but as soon as I include a test like

```
<%= ab_test :price_options %>
```

the program throws an error:

```
invalid value for Integer(): "{:conditions=>{:experiment_id=>\"price_options\""
```

In my controllers/application_controller.rb I have just:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  use_vanity
end
```

I didn't include a user identifier because I haven't built one into this app yet, but the Vanity docs say that if no argument is supplied Vanity will just use cookies instead, so that shouldn't be an issue. If anyone has any clue why this cryptic error is being thrown, I would be very appreciative!

Edit: I should add that I actually started a new rails app from scratch just to try and debug this. Literally all I did was start an app and install vanity following the readme instructions and I got this same error. This has happened on two different machines as well, so I suspect it's something obvious that I'm missing, but I can't be sure (else I wouldn't be here!).

EDIT: I've since decided to use the Split gem instead, and am having no troubles with it.

Comment: Can you post your experiment definition?

Comment: Also, where does the error get thrown? On loading the page that sets the cookie or when the user converts?

Comment: @phillbaker, sorry for the delay in response. The error gets thrown during test set up (so on the page that should set the cookie). The experiment definition is exactly the prototype used in the README:
    `ab_test "Price options" do
      description "Mirror, mirror on the wall, who's the better price of all?"
      alternatives 19, 25, 29
      metrics :signups
    end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is thrown because the current release version of Vanity uses the deprecated Rails find(:first) method, specifically:

```
 VanityParticipant.first(:conditions=>{ :experiment_id=>experiment.to_s, :identity=>identity.to_s })
```

This no longer works with Rails 4.1 but is fixed in the master branch of Vanity, so you can get round this in your Rails 4.1 app by adding:

```
gem 'vanity', :git => 'git@github.com:assaf/vanity', :branch => 'master'
```

to your Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

With

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  use_vanity
end
```

and

```
# experiments/price_options.rb
ab_test "Price options" do
  description "Mirror, mirror on the wall, who's the best price of all?"
  alternatives(19, 25, 29)
end
```

and

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end
end
```

the following view loads and sets a `vanity_id` cookie:

```
<h1>Static#home</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/static/home.html.erb</p>

<h2>Get started for only $<%= ab_test :price_options %> a month!</h2>
<%= link_to 'Make a new account', new_account_path %>
```

Comment: Yeah, this works for me too. I did the same thing a week ago though and consistently got this strange error. I'm going to chalk it up to the ghost in the machine, but I appreciate your time!